# error accuring when i created App.jsx after deleting App.js

Tags: reactjs

An error occurring when I created Appjsx after deleting Appjs, error is still there, is there any solution of this issue ?
what should i do what? where i am doing it wrong? is something I've missed ?

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Heading from "./Heading";
import Para from "./Para";
import List from "./List";

function App(){
 return (
    <>
    <Heading />
    <Para />
    <List/>
   
</>
);

}
export default App;
```

```html
src\App.jsx
  Line 14:1:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  12 |    
  13 | </>,
> 14 | )
     | ^
  15 |
  16 | }
  17 | export default App;
```

Comment: Restart your server, there is no problem with your `app.js` and please also comment that Heading, Para and List Component and add simple `p` tag and test with it, is it working or not

Comment: Thank you for your help..  the Issue was resolved...!!